# Serilog.Sinks.File support on windows 8.1 (WinRT)

Tags: serilog

I have developed an Windows8.1 store app for which I need to log info to a local file.

I could install Serilog nuget to my app but could not install the Serilog.Sinks.File (or .Console).

Could someone help me installing serilog on my app so that i could write to a file.

Thanks,
Atin..

Answer (score 0):

All the steps you need to add Serilog to your app is in the [Getting Started](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started) guide in Serilog's wiki.

Because you're using UWP, you have restrictions on where you can write in the filesystem, and typically you'd write the log to the app's local folder which you can get via `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path`

e.g.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Suspending += OnSuspending;

    var logFilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "App.log");

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .WriteTo.File(logFilePath)
        .CreateLogger();

    Log.Information("Hello UWP!");
}
```